# No adapter attached; skipping layout with RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

actually the title describe my problem.
I'm setting an adapter to a recyclerView but the problem is still showing up.
I think that the place which I'm calling to the method from to set adaptor  is not the problem but the facts... (or maybe it is not the issue).

The method wich set the adapter is showData();

**Edit:**
There is no error anymore (THX Rohit Arya) but I still can not see the pics (there is a blank page).

Code:

The MainFragment Class:

```
package com.sarusi.amit.smarts;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.util.Base64;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class MainFragment extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager manager;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private APIConfig apiConfig;

    public MainFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);

        APIConfig.names = new String[1];
        APIConfig.bitmaps = new Bitmap[1];

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.fragment_main_recyclerView);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

        adapter = new BoardAdapter(APIConfig.names, APIConfig.bitmaps);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);

        getBoardsData();

        return view;
    }

    private void getBoardsData() {

        class ConnectionTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
            ProgressDialog progressDialog;

            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(getContext(), "Fetching Data...", "A Trap", false, false);
                super.onPreExecute();
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                parseJSON(s);
                showData();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                BufferedReader bufferedReader;
                try {
                    URL url = new URL(apiConfig.IMAGES_URL);
                    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

                    bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

                    String json;
                    while ((json = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                        sb.append(json + "\n");
                    }

                    return sb.toString().trim();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }
        }

        ConnectionTask connectionTask = new ConnectionTask();
        connectionTask.execute();

    }

    public void showData () {
        adapter = new BoardAdapter(APIConfig.names, APIConfig.bitmaps);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }


    private void parseJSON(String json) {
        try {
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
            JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray(apiConfig.TAG_JSON_ARRAY);

            apiConfig = new APIConfig(jsonArray.length());

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject JSO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                APIConfig.names[i] = JSO.getString(apiConfig.TAG_NAME);
                APIConfig.bitmaps[i] = base64ToBitmap(JSO.getString(apiConfig.TAG_IMAGE));
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    private Bitmap base64ToBitmap(String b64) {
        byte[] imageAsBytes = Base64.decode(b64.getBytes(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        return BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(imageAsBytes, 0, imageAsBytes.length);
    }
}
```

The BoardAdapter Class:

```
package com.sarusi.amit.smarts;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by amit on 3/21/16.
 */
public class BoardAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<BoardAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    List<Board> boards;

    public BoardAdapter(String[] names, Bitmap[] images) {
        super();
        boards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < names.length; i++) {
            Board board = new Board();
            board.setImage(images[i]);
            board.setName(names[i]);
            boards.add(board);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.board_row, parent, false);
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        return viewHolder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        Board board = boards.get(position);
        holder.imageView.setImageBitmap(board.getImage());
        holder.name.setText(board.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return boards.size();
    }


    //The class for the viewHolder
    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView imageView;
        public TextView name;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            this.imageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.board_row_image);
            this.name = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.board_row_name);
        }
    }
}
```

fragment_main:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.sarusi.amit.smarts.MainFragment">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment_main_recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

</LinearLayout>
```

board_row:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/board_row_image"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/photo" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/board_row_name"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Trap" />


        </LinearLayout>


    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you show the fragment_main_layout.xml please

Comment: OK, the post edited.

Answer (score 0):

There is a certain time where the `RecyclerView` has no adapter atached.
You can  set the adapter when you initialize the `RecyclerView` with an empty list and then after you receive the data, update the list and call `notifyDataSetChanged` of the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

In `onCreateView`:

```
manager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());

recyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);

adapter = new BoardAdapter(APIConfig.names, APIConfig.bitmaps);
recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Here, `APIConfig.names` and `APIConfig.bitmaps` will be empty (**not** `null`).

Update these values `onPostExecute` of `AsyncTask` and call `notifyDataSetChanged` on the adapter.

Comment: I'm getting an error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.sarusi.amit.testa/com.sarusi.amit.smarts.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array

Comment: initialize these two arrays first `APIConfig.names, APIConfig.bitmaps`.

Comment: There is not an error anymore but the images don't showing up. Do you think that this is because of the adaptor?

Comment: "Update these values onPostExecute of AsyncTask and call notifyDataSetChanged on the adapter." Did you do this?

Comment: protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
                super.onPostExecute(s);
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                parseJSON(s);
                adapter = new BoardAdapter(APIConfig.names, APIConfig.bitmaps);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
Like that?

Comment: No, don't create new instance of `BoardAdapter`

Comment: something like this: `APIConfig.names = ""`, `APIConfig.bitmaps=""`

Comment: So the only thing that I need to do is to call for notifyDataSetChanged? Because the thing which you explained happened when I called to the parseJson(); method...